# Restricting User Access to Only Avalonia UI App on Windows 11

Tags: kiosk-mode, avaloniaui

I have developed a GUI app using Avalonia UI that, in some cases, launches another app through a specific interface and interacts with a local database.

I want to configure a user account on Windows 11 in such a way that the user only has access to the GUI app. I have learned about configuring kiosk mode on Windows, but I couldn't find my app in the list of available apps for kiosk mode.

I also came across the Shell Launcher, which allows configuring kiosk mode with third-party applications. However, I haven't found a comprehensive tutorial with examples.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve what I need? I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide an example of how to accomplish this.